# difference between two types of try catch block

Tags: java, try-catch

I recently saw a code...

```
try (   Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 2003);
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());){
        writer.write("data");
        writer.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

in this code `try catch` is used as `try` **(** `somecode` **){** `again some code` **}** `catch(){}`;
and it is working fine;

then i tried this code in this way

```
try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 2003);
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        writer.write("data");
        writer.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

here `try catch` is used as `try` **{** `again some code` **}** `catch(){}`;
which is also working... i was familiar with this pattern already...

so my question is ...

**What is the difference between these two ways of implementation of `try catch` ???**

Comment: Please read the [tutorial about try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: The first is a `try-with-resource` added in Java 7 - See [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details - in your example, it will automatically close the `Socket` and `Writer` when it exists the `try` context - unlike your second example, which is leaking resources

Comment: The second one doesn't close the Socket

Comment: if it is so then I can write the whole stuff between " ( " here " )  " between these brackets and leave the  " { " " } " curly brackets empty... why half code here and half there???

Comment: @SanjeevPrasadThakur Because the other two statements cannot be in the first part. Please **read the documentation** provided by the links in the previous comments.

Comment: Still waiting for an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution is an example of "try-with-resources", where you declare your resources accessible inside the `try` block.
This is always possible if you work with instances of `AutoClosable`. Java will close these resources for you in an implicit `finally` block after your last line inside the `try` terminates. This is extremely useful as you don't need to take care of releasing these resources on your own.

The second example just doesn't close the socket and writer and thus is not 100% functionally equal to solution 1.

Answer (score 0):

Java 1.7 introduced feature of try with resources where you don't need to explicitly close the resources which you open in try block

Prior to 1.7, you would always have to remember to close the resources in finally block.

Provided all the resources that you open in try() block implement autoclosable interface 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html

Answer (score 0):

The second needs `finally {}` to close `Socket & Writer`.The first will be closed automatically.And the first needs jdk1.7 or later.

Comment: was this thing brought only for these two socket and writer Classes??

Comment: io or network io  or other resources all need to be closed.such like inputstream,outputstream,reader,writer,,,